# "À + [infinitive]" as a noun?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, infinitif

I learned recently that "à boire" can act like a noun, by meaning the same thing as "quelque chose à boire".

But I learned also that there are some restrictions when used like this.

For example, all the following sentences are correct:

> Je veux quelque chose à boire.
>   Je veux **à boire**.

But if I try to use *à boire* where I could use a different noun, such as *la boisson*, sometimes it makes incorrect sentences:

> Je veux quelque chose à boire de chaud.  <-- OK
>   Je veux *à boire* de chaud. <-- **INCORRECT**
>
> Qu'est-ce que tu penses de quelque chose à boire ? <-- OK
>   Qu'est-ce que tu penses de à boire ? <-- **INCORRECT**
>
> Qu'est-ce que tu penses de *la boisson* ? <-- OK
>   Qu'est-ce que tu penses de *à boire* ? <-- **INCORRECT**
>
> Est-ce que tu veux *la boisson* chaude ? <-- OK
>   Est-ce que tu veux *à boire* chaude ? <-- **INCORRECT**

It seems that I can't use adjectives (such as *de chaud* or *chaud*) with *à boire*, nor can *de* preceed *à boire*.

What are the rules about how **à [infinitive]** is allowed to be used like a noun?

Comment: "Je veux à boire de chaud." n'est pas correct

Comment: @Plue thanks; editting my question now.

Comment: seems to me that `Je veux quelque chose à boire de chaud` is not correct, I would use  `Je veux quelque chose de chaud à boire` instead

Comment: also, `Qu'est-ce que tu pense de quelque chose à boire?` sounds really REALLY weird to me  `Que dirais-tu de boire quelque chose` is way better ;)

Comment: Your case 2 and 3 are incorrect at the very least in part because French simply does not (Unsurprisingly. In fact, I suspect not a single Indo-European language allows it) allow prepositions to combine this way.

Comment: @Circeus Good point, but they also don't tend to nominalize prep. + inf. either. One suspects that « à boire » might not be analyzable as a composite.

Answer (score 1):

It is incorrect, unhelpful at least, to think of the construction "à boire" as a noun. It is more an abbreviation of the phrase "quelque chose à boire". As in English, if you want to use an adjective, you need the "something" to attach it to: "something hot to drink" > "quelque chose de chaud à boire" or else "une boisson chaude à boire".

Comment: I would add that the sentences `Je veux à boire.` and  `Je veux à manger.`  are expressions. It is therefore incorrect to add adjectives to those particular sentences since they are in a way "incorrect" French sentences.